# What scriptures mention chanting Runa Vimochana Narasimha Stotram relieves debts?

Tags: narasimha, identification-request, stotra

There is a belief that if anybody chants the Runa Vimochana Narasimha Stotram he can be relieved from his debts. Is that belief mentioned in any scriptures?

---

EDIT: Here is the Stotram:

> ॥ श्रीनरसिंहऋणमोचनस्तोत्र ॥
>
> श्रीगणेशाय नमः । 
>  ॐ देवानां कार्यसिध्यर्थं सभास्तम्भसमुद्भवम्
>   ।
>  श्रीनृसिंहं महावीरं नमामि ऋणमुक्तये ॥ १॥
>
> लक्ष्म्यालिङ्गितवामाङ्गं भक्तानामभयप्रदम् ।
>  श्रीनृसिंहं महावीरं
>   नमामि ऋणमुक्तये ॥ २॥
>
> प्रह्लादवरदं श्रीशं दैतेश्वरविदारणम् ।
>  श्रीनृसिंहं महावीरं नमामि
>   ऋणमुक्तये ॥ ३॥
>
> स्मरणात्सर्वपापघ्नं कद्रुजं विषनाशनम् ।
>  श्रीनृसिंहं महावीरं नमामि
>   ऋणमुक्तये ॥ ४॥
>
> अन्त्रमालाधरं शङ्खचक्राब्जायुधधारिणम् । 
>  श्रीनृसिंहं महावीरं नमामि
>   ऋणमुक्तये ॥ ५॥
>
> सिंहनादेन महता दिग्दन्तिभयदायकम् ।
>  श्रीनृसिंहं महावीरं नमामि
>   ऋणमुक्तये ॥ ६॥
>
> कोटिसूर्यप्रतीकाशमभिचारिकनाशनम् । 
>  श्रीनृसिंहं महावीरं नमामि
>   ऋणमुक्तये ॥ ७॥
>
> वेदान्तवेद्यं यज्ञेशं ब्रह्मरुद्रादिसंस्तुतम् । 
>  श्रीनृसिंहं
>   महावीरं नमामि ऋणमुक्तये ॐ ॥ ८॥
>
> इदं यो पठते नित्यं ऋणमोचकसंज्ञकम् ।
>  अनृणीजायते सद्यो धनं
>   शीघ्रमवाप्नुयात् ॥ ९॥
>
> ॥ इति श्रीनृसिंहपुराणे ऋणमोचनस्तोत्रं सम्पूर्णम् ॥

**Source** : [Sanskritdocuments.org](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/narasinhaRiNamochanastotra.html?lang=sa)

In Youtube you can hear from the below link--

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTymjIp4Qoo

Comment: The last line says "॥ इति श्रीनृसिंहपुराणे ऋणमोचनस्तोत्रं सम्पूर्णम् ॥"  If that's true,  it might be a part of Nrusimha Purana.

Comment: From the very meaning of the ऋण RNA (meaning debt) , and विमोचन (meaning liberation), it is self evident that the stotram is recited for relief from debt, (the literal meaning of the name of the stotra itself is its reference)and from the sankalpa vakya (epilogue), इति श्रीनृसिंहपुराणे ( ithi Shri Narasimha Purane ) , indicates it is  part of Narasimha purana.

(Afaik, there are also
 Rna vimochana Ganapati stotram
 Rna vimochana Angaraka stotram)

Answer (score 3):

The seer of "Runa Vimochana Narasimha Stotram" is Sri [Vadiraja Tirtha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadiraja_Tirtha) swami. He is a Dvaitha Vedanti and you can read more about him from [here](https://sodematha.in/history).

Although many sources suggest the Stotra as a part of Narasimha Purana [1](http://srinarasimhakutumbam.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Narasimha_Stotram.pdf), it is actually given by [Vadiraju](http://shivallibrahmins.com/great-acharyas/sri-sri-vadiraja-teertharu/), who is a great saint in Madhva parampara. [Sri Lakshmi Narasimha Purana published by Tirumala](https://ebooks.tirumala.org/downloads/sri_lakshminarasimha_puranam.pdf#page=74) mentioned Vadirajaru Tirtha as the author of the Stotra.

You can find the same in several other sources [1](https://madhwafestivals.com/2017/01/02/strotras-written-by-sri-vadirajaru/), [2](https://www.raaga.com/sanskrit/songs/vadiraja-krutha-narasimha-stothram-85633), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPN8e2J2dyU), [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cTGpBtxpO4).